# Custom WordPress PHP code to display other posts in a post breaks my comments

Tags: wordpress

I'm running the following code in my WordPress site and while it works, it breaks my comments. I suspect I'm not resetting the query properly.

```
<?php

// name: posts you may also like

// get the current post's "post id."
$postId = get_the_ID();

$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'post__not_in' => array($postId),
  'orderby' => 'rand',
]);

$html = '<div style="font-weight:bold;">OTHER INTERESTING POSTS:</div><ul>';

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    
    $title = get_the_title();
    $permalink = get_the_permalink();
    
     $html .= <<<EOD
  <li><a href="$permalink">$title</a></li>
EOD;

  }
}

$html .= '</ul>';

echo($html);

?>
```

Comment: Do I just add: wp_reset_query() ? This appears to be working, but is it the correct way to do this?

Comment: Yes. This is enough.  but whats break your comments? any error?

Comment: If you are using Custom query on wordpress than you have to reset that query so it will not effect on main wordpress query. You can use `wp_reset_query()` OR `wp_reset_postdata()`. For difference between this you can prefer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144344/199756

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
<?php
// name: posts you may also like

// get the current post's "post id."
$postId = get_the_ID();

$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post__not_in'   => array($postId),
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
] );

?> 

<div style="font-weight:bold;">OTHER INTERESTING POSTS:</div>
    <ul>
        <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) { while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
            $title     = get_the_title();
            $permalink = get_the_permalink(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $permalink; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></li>
        <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, wp_reset_query() appears to work.

Comment: I will change to wp_reset_postdata() as this seems to address the issue of using query_posts as well. Thank you!